# Django request.META

Tags: django, request, metadata

If I want to display more than one item of the request.META dictionary:

How can I put e.g. two in this string format:

```
def myurl(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are %s" % request.META['USER'], "Your IP Adress is " % request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

does not work.

Also, any ideas how I can display/extract selective items of that dictionary.

If I want to run more than one via a template. How would I insert that in the html template:

e.g.

{{request.META }} . Does that works for all? How can I display them one in each line?

if I want e.g. just:

> HTTP_COOKIE
>
> QUERY_STRING
>
> HTTP_CONNECTION

What would be the best way to display that 3 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** (after reading OP's comment to this answer)

The `template` here is just a string with embedded format options.

1) It doesn't have to be called `template`

```
def myurl(request):
    place_holders = "You are %(user)s; your IP address is %(ipaddress)s"
    options = dict(user = request.META['USER'], ipaddress = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    return HttpResponse(place_holders % options)
```

2) You can do away with it altogether make it inline. This is purely a matter of coding style/preference.

```
def myurl(request):
    return HttpResponse("You are %s; your IP address is %s" % (request.META['USER'], request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']))
```

**Original Answer**

Quick and dirty answer to the first part of your question:

```
def myurl(request):
    template = "You are %(user)s; your IP address is %(ipaddress)s"
    options = dict(user = request.META['USER'], ipaddress = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    return HttpResponse(template % options)
```

Comment: Nice. really works. How can it work without a template you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Use RequestContext:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def myurl(request):
    return render_to_response('template.html', {},
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You will then have access to request.META and everything it contains. You may use the debug template tag to print your context.

Comment: What does RequestContext do? Is that another way to get META?